# Vuforia iOS minimum target 7.0?

Tags: ios, target, vuforia

I want wo create an app only for iOS7 Devices.

I have downloaded the latest Vuforia SDK and sample app and selected the iOS target to 7.0.

The result -> 38 error messages from the vuforia library. For a errorfree app, I need to set the iOS deployment target to 6.1.... :-(

Is there a way to allow iOS7 devices only?

Comment: This is explained here:

https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/ios/ios-compiling-vuforia-project-xcode-51

 it works -> after changing the C++ Standard library to "libstdc++ (GNU C++ standard library)" !!!!